# Is it worth resubmitting updated application materials a second time over poor sentence flow?

Tags: faculty-application, application-cover-letter, visiting, proofreading

I am a fourth year doctoral candidate in Experimental Psychology who should be graduating this summer with my Ph.D.

I recently resubmitted application materials for a visiting position one month after the deadline for one position and a few days after a deadline for another because I had noticed an institution's specific name from my previous application was on there by accident.

However, I noticed two sentences had extremely bad flow. Here they are: "Finally, I am interested in advising students if there is ever the opportunity to do so. I
would also like to start and advise an Autism Spectrum Club branch if there is ever a chance to do so as well." For the applications that are due tomorrow (March 1st), this is how I edited it, "Finally, I am interested in advising students if there is ever the opportunity to do so. I would also like to start and advise an Autism Spectrum Club branch."

Is it worth emailing the chair and giving another resubmission that they can forward to the committee (they already did so for my first one)?

Comment: It's not bad flow. It's repeating a phrase almost word for word, and using more words than you needed.

Comment: CrimsonDark's answer from your other question is still very apposite here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/208054/is-it-possible-that-my-previous-milestone-projects-masters-thesis-quals-pro You spend an inordinate amount of time worrying about, frankly, utter non-sense and your quality of life would improve substantially if you learned how to handle this appropriately with the help of a professional instead of trying to outsource this task to Academia SE.

Answer (score 10):

No, don't do that. You already resubmitted once, and something trivial like this would just make you stand out in a bad way. Save resubmitting for like "I got a huge grant."

Answer (score 4):

You worry too much. Individual sentences do not make or break applications. You did your job in submitting your file, now move on mentally and be productive with things that help you build a future career.